# Analyzing survey data

Tags: survey

I have survey data in which students rate their beliefs on a likert scale (1 to 5) about certain items related to teaching. The instrument has four sub scales. Students took this survey at six different time points until they graduated. I would like to know whether some items or sub scales predict a student's likelihood of continuing/graduating from the program. Each student was given a unique identifier, so I have a way of linking their scores, but some students did not take the survey at certain time points. I know how many students remained in the program at each time point, but I don't know exactly who those students were. What statistical tests might I use for this, that also accounts for missing data? Or, is there literature that supports removing missing data?

Comment: Is this even possible? You want to predict whether students would remain in the program or graduate, but you said you don't know at each time period whether students remain or not. No statistical test will help you with 100% missing dependent variables.

Comment: @indigochild To clarify, I know most of the students who completed the program because they took the final survey (and I know their unique identifier). I also know exactly how many students there were at each time point. There are a few missing data from students who did not take the survey at certain time points.